# Accept value greater than zero and the value can be even 0.01 or 0.10

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, decimalformat

I have a method in which i try to validate the value and the value can be anything but should not be `zero`

```
function change(){
    var bill= document.getElementById("myTextField")
    var RE = /^(?!^0*$)(?!^0*\.0*$)^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    if(RE.test(bill)){
       alert("True");
    }else{
      alert("False");
    }    
}
```

[JSD FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/antoalphi/dzmf9nqp/)

but this returns false even if i enter right value.

```
the minimum value should be greater than 0 and maximum value is 99999.99
```

Comment: That's an impressive regexp, but why not just convert the value to a float and test that?

Comment: @HeadCode would you show some example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function change(){
    var stBill = Math.round(document.getElementById("myTextField").value * 100)/ 100;
    var RE = /^(?!^0*$)(?!^0*\.0*$)^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    if(RE.test(stBill)){
       alert("True");
    }else{
      alert("False");
    }       
}
```

#### Test the value not the element, you are selecting the element not its vale

### [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzmf9nqp/3/)

Comment: I can't see why this would be valid, it doesn't make sense.. it's saying that 0.989 if bigger than 0.99 !!

Comment: @decebal i have updated the answer and fiddle and applied rounding

Answer (score 3):

A little off topic from those who answered correctly, but it might be easier to just convert the value to a float and test that.

```
function change(){
    var stBill = document.getElementById("myTextField").value;
    var num = parseFloat(stBill, 10);
    if(num > 0 && num <= 99999.99){
        alert("True");
    }else{
        alert("False");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't test the `stBill`, the input element object itself, against the regex. You need to test it's value instead:

```
RE.test(stBill.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

try fixing

```
RE.test(stBill.value)
```

or

```
var stBill = document.getElementById("myTextField").value;
```

you should be looking for value and not the element. :)